# Python: Testing if a value is present in a defaultdict list

Tags: python, list, collections, dictionary

I want test whether a string is present within any of the list values in a defaultdict.

For instance:

```
from collections import defaultdict  
animals = defaultdict(list)  
animals['farm']=['cow', 'pig', 'chicken']  
animals['house']=['cat', 'rat']
```

I want to know if 'cow' occurs in any of the lists within animals.

```
'cow' in animals.values()  #returns False
```

I want something that will return "True" for a case like this.  Is there an equivalent of:

```
'cow' in animals.values()
```

for a defaultdict?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't let `defaultdict` confuse you.  If you had a regular `dict`, you would still have the same issue.  `animals.values()` is a list of lists, not a list of strings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

defaultdict is no different from a regular dict in this case.  You need to iterate over the values in the dictionary:

```
any('cow' in v for v in animals.values())
```

or more procedurally:

```
def in_values(s, d):
    """Does `s` appear in any of the values in `d`?"""
    for v in d.values():
        if s in v:
            return True
    return False

in_values('cow', animals)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
any("cow" in lst for lst in animals.itervalues())
```

Answer (score -1):

This example will flatten the list, checking each element and will return True or False as follows:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict  
>>> animals = defaultdict(list)  
>>> animals['farm']=['cow', 'pig', 'chicken']  
>>> animals['house']=['cat', 'rat']

>>> 'cow' in [x for y in animals.values() for x in y]
True
```